# Mathematical Optimisation of Martingale Strategy.

Tags: calculus, optimization, gambling

Here is a short background of how the strategy works.Your next bet should always be enough to make up for all your previous losses and earn some little profit.E.g if your losses were 10 dollars stake **(20+1)**dollars as your next bet on a market with 2.0 odds or more.

I have collected data on virtual horse racing market that has odds that meet the criteria.I have seen that on average the largest lose streak is 10 in a day out of 200 bets in a day.
Here is some sample data for the lose streaks.

> 0(43) 1(27) 2(14) 3(11) 4(4) 5(2) 6(1) 7(2) 8(1) 9(1) 10(0) 11(1)

- 0 Lose Streaks Happened 43 times(consecutive win)
- 1 Lose Streaks    Happened 27 times...etc

Now here comes my question is it possible to calculate the best staking strategy using a budget of **1000 dollars** and minimum bet of **1 dollar**.I had this idea where you would stake really high lets say **10 dollars** as your starting bet of the martingale strategy and then "restart" the betting session when a lose streak of lets say **5** is reached.My intuition says you will make more money in the long run before the dreaded *10-12 lose streak* comes your way.

In this example lets call the 10 dollar**[startbet]** and lose streak  5 as **[resetter]** and another variable that we could toss in is a **[profitAdder]** which basically is the 1 dollar in my first example *(20+1)*.So is there a sort of educated guess or formula for coming up with the best values for the above variables.